# Optimizing a MySQL query containing subselects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have what could be described as a big fat MySQL query that I need to optimize. What the query does is selects data related to the processing of backlinks.

By backlink processing I mean that about 100,000 links are added to a database. The links are selected and curled in batches looking for a backlink to my website.

The information I'm selecting in this query are:

- `complete` - has processing finished (bool 1 or 0)
- `current_step` - What step out of 3 are we on (1, 2 or 3)
- `percent` - what percentage done am I with the step that I'm on (0.0-100.0)
- `total_rows` - a complete count of all rows in the database with
  that table key id (integer)
- `live_rows` - the number of links found with a live backlink to my page (integer)
- `dead_rows` - the number of links found that do not have a backlink (integer)

Note: Current Step is calculated by looking at the MAX() value of the `checked` column. We check links two times if the link isn't found. So when the tool first starts running all of the `checked` values are set to zero (because processing hasnt started yet) so we want the current step to be step 1. We then process all the rows and all of the `checked` values are set to 1 and the percent will return as 100.00 for step 1, the program then starts the double check of links that were found to be dead the first time. As the second check goes some of the rows are then set to 2 so MAX(checked) returns 2 for step two. Once step two is done the program changes the `processing_complete` column to 1 and we return 3 as the the current step for done. We return 3 because it causes the UI to change to a done status.

I have 2 tables, here's their general structure. Note that `tablekey_id` is a foreign key from `google_sort_backlink_domains` back to the `id` column in `google_sort_tablekey`.

**google_sort_tablekey:**

- `id` - Primary key, index column
- `unique_id` - Unique hash used as a unique identifier to this tool run
- `processing_completed` - bool flag set to 1 when processing competes

**google_sort_backlink_domains:**

- `id` - Primary key, index column
- `tablekey_id` - Foreign key to google_sort_tablekey
- `checked` - bool flag set to 1 when the link was curled and then
- `link_found` - bool flag set to 1 if a backlink was found during the first or second check
- `link_href` - String, link to the page

Here is a very small example of what that data may look like

```
google_sort_tablekey:
id     unique_id       processing_completed
23     35799756448     1
24     78698778978     0

google_sort_backlink_domains:
id     tablekey_id     checked     link_found     link_href
11     23              1           0              http://www.website.com/1...
12     24              0           0              http://www.website.com/2...
13     23              1           1              http://www.website.com/3...
14     24              1           1              http://www.website.com/4...
15     24              1           1              http://www.website.com/5...
16     24              0           0              http://www.website.com/6...
```

Here is my query that works however when I deal with a data set of 100,000 rows it takes way to long. Ive added spaces to help with readability and I also hard coded in an id of 24, this would be set with a variable in production.

```
SELECT `processing_completed` AS complete,

ROUND((SELECT((SUM(IF((`link_found` = 1 OR `checked` >= (SELECT MAX(`checked`) 
    FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 24)), 1, 0)) / SUM(1))*100) AS percent
FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 24), 1) AS percent,

CASE WHEN `processing_completed` = 1 THEN 3 WHEN MAX(`checked`) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(`checked`) END AS current_step,

(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `google_sort_backlinks` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 24) AS total_rows,

(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 24) AS unique_domains,

(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 24 AND `link_found` = 1) AS live_rows,

(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 24 
AND `checked` >= (
SELECT CASE WHEN `processing_completed` = 1 THEN 3 WHEN MAX(`checked`) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(`checked`) END FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 24
)) AS dead_rows

FROM `google_sort_tablekey` AS tablekey
JOIN `google_sort_backlink_domains` AS domain ON domain.tablekey_id = tablekey.id
WHERE domain.tablekey_id = 24
```

Can anyone help me make my query more efficient so that it can handle 100,000+ rows in the google_sort_backlink_domains table? Please and thank you!

Comment: First: Are your tables properly indexed? Second: Use `explain select...` to check the execution plan and check which files need to be indexed. See the reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Yes I do use indexes however now I didnt have one on the checked column. I have added that now thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Query takes 132.4556 sec with the indexes :(

Comment: How is your MySQL tuned? Maybe your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to the useless default. This is presuming you're using InnoDB, which you should be if you value your data.

Comment: You may find that splitting your query into several smaller queries decreases the time taken in total.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this where the more 'constant' calculations are placed in variables and the subqueries replaced with aggregates.

```
SET @id = 24;
SET @den = (SELECT SUM(1) FROM google_sort_backlink_domains);
SET @max = (SELECT MAX(checked) FROM google_sort_backlink_domains WHERE tablekey_id=@id);
SET @n = (SELECT 
              CASE 
                  WHEN processing_completed = 1 THEN 3 
                  WHEN MAX(checked) = 0 THEN 1 
                  ELSE MAX(checked) END 
          FROM google_sort_backlink_domains WHERE tablekey_id=@id);

SELECT 
    processing_completed AS complete,
    SUM(IF(link_found=1 OR checked>=@max, 1, 0)) / @den AS percent, 
    CASE 
        WHEN processing_completed=1 THEN 3 
        WHEN MAX(checked)=0 THEN 1 
        ELSE MAX(checked)
    END AS current_step,
    COUNT(back.id) AS total_rows,
    COUNT(domain.id) AS unique_domains,
    SUM(link_found) AS live_rows,
    SUM(IF(checked>= @n), 1, 0) AS dead_rows
FROM google_sort_tablekey AS tablekey 
JOIN google_sort_backlink AS back ON back.tablekey_id = tablekey.id
JOIN google_sort_backlink_domains AS domain ON domain.tablekey_id = tablekey.id
WHERE domain.tablekey_id = @id
GROUP BY processing_completed
```

Comment: Im getting a SQL Syntax error near the end  near '), 1, 0) AS dead_rows FROM google_sort_tablekey AS tablekey JOIN google_sort_' at line 12 - Im trying to debug it but no luck yet. NEVERMIND: It was a typo with the table name.